# How to Validate Employee Id in Importing File in .CSV format to SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv

How to Validate Employee Id in Importing File in .CSV format  to SQL?

*a code that check if the data is already exist.
-->sample: if the Employee Id already exist it promts "Employee ID already Exist"..

Comment: Make the employee id column unique. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html

Answer (score 0):

if the rows in csv, you can make a array of csv rows.

```
$list =array();
$id  = array();


while( ($rows= getcsv($hande)) !== false)
{
  array_push($list, $rows);
  array_push($id, $rows['emplyee_id']);
}
```

then check mysql or database

```
$check_id = implode(",", $id);
$que = "select employ_id from table where employ_id in ($check_id)";
```

at this time you can find employ_ids from database.

if  you make employee_id column unique, your code would be like this

```
$result=mysqli_query($db_con", "insert into table (employ_id) values ('$empoy_id')";
if($result == false) // if employ_id alreay exists in table $result is false
{
}
```

but as i know,  the best way using index  is checking key is exists before inserting data not after inserting query failed.

Answer (score 0):

```html
This is my code:

`<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
 $a=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
 echo $a;
 
 $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$connect) {
die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
} 
//your database name
$cid =mysql_select_db('cgi_warehouse',$connect);

// path where your CSV file is located
//define('CSV_PATH','C:/xampp/htdocs/');
//<!-- C:\\xampp\\htdocs -->
// Name of your CSV file
$csv_file = $a;

if (($getfile = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
         $data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",");
   while (($data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
     //$num = count($data);
    //echo $num;
        //for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $result = $data;
         $str = implode(",", $result);
         $slice = explode(",", $str);

            $col1 = $slice[0];
            $col2 = $slice[1];
            $col3 = $slice[2];
   $col4 = $slice[3];
   $col5 = $slice[4];
   $col6 = $slice[5];
   $col7 = $slice[6];
   $col8 = $slice[7];
   $col9 = $slice[8];
   $col10 = $slice[9];
   $col11 = $slice[10];
   $col12 = $slice[11];
   $col13 = $slice[12];
   $col14 = $slice[13];
   $col15 = $slice[14];
   $col16 = $slice[15];




   
$query = "INSERT INTO tools(tools_id, item_description, category_id, sn, qty, price, supplier, frm, location, ref_no, sender, receiver, date_receive, date_added, status, remarks) VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."','".$col5."','".$col6."','".$col7."','".$col8."','".$col9."','".$col10."','".$col11."','".$col12."','".$col13."','".$col14."','".$col15."','".$col16."')";
$s=mysql_query($query, $connect );
}
}



echo "<script>alert('Record successfully uploaded.');window.location.href='#';</script>";
mysql_close($connect);
}
?>`
```